# Can ApacheDS LDAP change root user name?

Tags: security, ldap, openldap, root, apache-ds

ApacheDS 1.5 has the following account by default.

Bind dn or user: uid=admin,ou=system

Bind password: secret

i would like to change it to the following to avoid making changes in my code

Bind dn or user: cn=root,dc=ldap,dc=local

Bind password: secret

I figured out how to switch dc=example,dc=com to dc=ldap,dc=local and i imported my LDIF backup successfully. I just can't use my old connection string. I was using openldap before.

There isn't any config in the example instance that specify uid=admin,ou=system as the administrator, so i am stucked.

Please help, Thanks in advance.